# Load animation after another using pure javascript, HTML, and CSS without keyframes

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, effects

I am new to javascript and I have done one image to fade in, but the second image wont fade in next.
See HTML and Javascript. With the use of pure HTML, CSS AND JS without keyframes for animation. No libraries or framework to use.

**For HTML:**

```
    <div id="female" style="opacity: 0;"> 
        <img id="fem" src="./images/female.png" onload="female()">
    </div> 

    <div id="headline1" style="opacity: 0;">
        <img id="t1" src="./images/headline1.png" onload="headline1()">
    </div>
</div>
```

**For JS code:**

//FEMALE ANIMATION

```
function female () {
var opacity = 0; 
var intervalID = 0; 
window.onload = fadeIn; 

function fadeIn() { 
    setInterval(show, 150); 
} 

function show() { 
    var body = document.getElementById("female"); 
    opacity = Number(window.getComputedStyle(body) 
                    .getPropertyValue("opacity")); 
    if (opacity < 1) { 
        opacity = opacity + 0.1; 
        body.style.opacity = opacity 
    } else { 
        clearInterval(intervalID); 
    } 
}}
```

//HEADLINE 1 ANIMATION

```
function headline1 () {
var opacity = 0; 
var intervalID = 0; 
window.onload = fadeIn; 

function fadeIn() { 
    setInterval(show, 150); 
} 

function show() { 
    var body = document.getElementById("headline1"); 
    opacity = Number(window.getComputedStyle(body) 
                    .getPropertyValue("opacity")); 
    if (opacity < 1) { 
        opacity = opacity + 0.1; 
        body.style.opacity = opacity 
    } else { 
        clearInterval(intervalID); 
    } 
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the functions `female()` and `headline1()` assign their own functions to `window.onload`. This will cause the 2 functions impact each other.

You can use [window.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of `window.onload` to solve this issue.

Considering that both your `female()` and `headline1()` functions are very similar, it is a good idea to use a single function with a parameter to specify the ID of the image to animate.

```
function animateImage(id, opacity) {
  var intervalID = 0;
  window.addEventListener('load', fadeIn);

  function fadeIn() { 
    setInterval(show, 150);
  }

  function show() { 
    var body = document.getElementById(id); 
    opacity = Number(window.getComputedStyle(body) 
                    .getPropertyValue("opacity")); 
    if (opacity < 1) { 
        opacity = opacity + 0.1; 
        body.style.opacity = opacity 
    } else { 
        clearInterval(intervalID); 
    } 
  }
}
```